# Remove row from appended table when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a beginner and know only basics of javascript and MVC. Now I need to remove the corresponding row from the appended table whenever the row is unchecked..
This is my table ...

```
    <table id="sortabletable" class="tab sortable">

    <tr class = trow>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AId)
            </td>
             <td>                 
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UId)
            </td>

             <td><input type="checkbox" name="thecheckbox" value="@item.TXId" class ="cbox" checked/></td>
         </tr> 
</table>
<table class="tab" id="tlist">
<tbody>  
</tbody>
</table>
```

and here's my Jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        _this = $(this);
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            row.find('td:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(3)').hide();
            var row = _this.closest("tr").clone();
            $('#tlist').append(row);
        } else {
            // i dont know
        }
    });
});
```

I don't know how to select the row based on checked value from an appended table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a combination of `closest` and `remove`

```
$('input.cbox').on('change', function() {
      var _this = $(this);
      if(this.checked) {
        var row = _this.closest("tr").clone();
        row.find('td:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(3)').hide();

        row.data('id' , this.value);
        $('#tlist').append(row);
      }
      else {
          $('[data-id="'+ this.id +'"]', '#tlist').remove()
      }
});
```

Comment: But it will remove row from my checking table... I need to remove it from table #tlist, the appended one.

Comment: I don't think your question is clear.. Can you paste part of the rendered HTML and what you are expecting

Comment: I'm trying to create a new table #tlist from the other table based on check box. So when I check, the entire row will automatically add to the new table and it's working successfully. Similarly when I uncheck , that specific row must be removed from the new table #tlist.

Comment: Assume the input has a id property, when you click the checkbox after cloning the row , add a attribute called `data-id` for the row. The when unchecked remove that element using the `data-id` property. Check edited code

Comment: Thanks bro!!.. But why can't we use the 'value' attribute as it's unique in both table rows?

Comment: It's unique. It's an auto incremented value from db. But I don't know how to fetch the value attribute from the new table and remove the row . It would b very grateful if you can help me on that

Comment: Then set it this way `row.data('id' , this.value);` remaining code should do

Comment: I think that you have missed something on your `else` part, the parameters passed to the `$` need a comma between them.